# Calculate the BMI, using mass and height, and use if else statements to print if the user is overweight, healthy or underweight, keep getting an error

Tags: swift

I keep getting this error Cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type 'Double' swift error

I don't know what to try

```
import UIKit

func calculateBmi (mass : Double, height: Double) -> Double
{
    let bmi = mass / (height * 2)

if (bmi > 25)
{
    return ("Your bmi is \(bmi) therefore you are overweight")
}
else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25)
{
    return ("Your bmi is \(bmi) therefore you are of normal weight")
}
else
{
    return ("Your bmi is \(bmi) therefore you are underweight")
}

}

print(calculateBmi(mass: 75, height: 1.55448))
```

This is the error i keep on getting Cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type 'Double' swift error

Comment: Your function declares that it returns `Double` but you are trying to return strings.

Comment: Unrelated but you don't need to use the `(` and `)` with `return` in Swift.

Comment: You should uses a `switch` statement for something like that. They're a lot cleaner in terms of being able to glance at what's going on with the code than bunch of if-else statements. Also, you're returning a string, but your method says to return a double.

Comment: Three people spent time answering your question. What happened with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use swift, but reading the [on line manual page about functions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html)

> func calculateBmi (mass : Double, height: Double) -> Double

declares a function that returns a Double. All your return statements appear to be trying to return a string and I guess that the conversion is impossible.
It should probably be

> func calculateBmi (mass : Double, height: Double) -> String

Just an aside, the line

> else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25)

needs only say

> else if (bmi >= 18.5)

as you have already eliminated all values >25 in the first part of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

For what you're doing, I think a `switch` statement makes far more sense. Additionally, you're returning a string inside your method, but the signature says to return a double.

The following code should fix the issues that I mentioned above:

```
func calculateBmi(mass: Double, height: Double) -> String {
    let bmi = mass / (height * 2)

    switch bmi {
    case 0..<18.5:
        return ("Your bmi is \(bmi) therefore you are underweight")
    case 18.5..<25:
        return ("Your bmi is \(bmi) therefore you are of normal weight")
    case 25...:
        return ("Your bmi is \(bmi) therefore you are overweight")
    default:
        return "" // this is to shut up the compiler
    }
}

print(calculateBmi(mass: 75, height: 1.55448))
```

For now, Swift only supports primitives for `enum` statements, so you can't use something like a `Range` to create an `enum`, which is why I have a default case which returns a blank value. Every valid case should be captured by the three ranges I specified in the cases.

OK...so if you want to get a bit fancier, you could just create a `struct` and utilize a computed `var` for the BMI calculation and utilize `String(format:)`

Here's what that looks like:

```
struct BMIStruct: CustomStringConvertible {
    let mass: Double
    let height: Double
    var bmi: Double {
        return mass / (height * 2)
    }

    // This is a var to conform to the CustomStringCovertible protocol
    var description: String {
        switch bmi {
        case 0..<18.5:
            return String(format: "Your BMI is %.1f, therefore you are underweight", bmi)
        case 18.5..<25:
            return String(format: "Your BMI is %.1f, therefore you are of normal weight", bmi)
        case 25...:
            return String(format: "Your BMI is %.1f, therfor you are overweight", bmi)
        default:
            return "" // this is to shut up the compiler
        }
    }
}

let normalWeight = BMIStruct(mass: 75, height: 1.55448)
print(normalWeight.bmi)
print(normalWeight.description)
```

Comment: Whilst I don't speak swift, it looks to me like C made difficult :) ! As for using a switch / case construct and a structure, isn't this just adding unnecessary complexity to something that is simple (if / else if / else) and requires additional redundant code just to satisfy a grouchy compiler. I was always taught KISS.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code as correction of your existing code . For good practice use switch case as [Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57024065/7643240) mentioned here.

```
import UIKit

    func calculateBmi (mass : Double, height: Double) -> String
    {
        let bmi = mass / (height * 2)

       if (bmi > 25)
       {
           return ("Your bmi is \(bmi) therefore you are overweight")
       }
       else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25)
       {
           return ("Your bmi is \(bmi) therefore you are of normal weight")
       }
       else
       {
           return ("Your bmi is \(bmi) therefore you are underweight")
       }

    }

    print(calculateBmi(mass: 75, height: 1.55448))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a String not a Double

func calculateBmi(mass : Double, height: Double) -> String {
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, people has already answered your question clearly, but I want to point out that the equation for calculating BMI is weight / (height * height), not (height * 2). The height should be squared, not multiply it by 2. Maybe this will help your code.

But if you want you can use the `pow` function

```
let bmi = mass / pow(height, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
func calculateBmi(height: Double, weight: Double) -> String {
        let heightInMeters  = height * 0.01
        let bmi = weight / (heightInMeters * heightInMeters)
        
        if (bmi < 18.5) {
            return "Underweight"
        } else if (bmi >= 18 && bmi < 30){
            return "Normal"
        }
        else if (bmi >= 30) {
            return "Obese"
        }
        return "Invalid BMI"
    }
```